# AddingtblSettings.dataSource = self doesn't load the viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

My `ViewController` Class is like this

```
import UIKit

class SubscriptionViewController:    
UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblSettings: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var vwTitle: UIView!

let mutableDictionary = ["Business","News","Sports","Entertainment","Crime","Politics"]

var imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   tblSettings.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
   self.tblSettings.delegate = self
   self.tblSettings.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mutableDictionary.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SettingsCell") as! SettingsTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil
    {
        //tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UICustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UICustomTableViewCell")
        tableView.registerClass(SettingsTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SettingsCell")

        cell = SettingsTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "SettingsCell")

    }
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    // Custom view options
    let image=UIImage.init(named: "SettingsUnChecked")

    imageView.image=image

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    cell.accessoryView = imageView//UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))

    cell.accessoryView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    if let label = cell.lblName{
        label.text = mutableDictionary[indexPath.row]
        label.textColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    return cell

}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

My problem is my viewcontroller doesnt load. But if I commented `tblSettings.datasource=self` my view controller appear. Whats the reason for this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: I think delegate is ok for tableview implementation, use storyboard to assign delegate & datasource avoid doing it in code plus if you table is not loading do `self.tblSettings.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I tried to set delegate and datasource from storyboard but the problem is when I set both my Viewcontroller doesnt appear.It just waiting at the LaunchView

Comment: Remove `UITableViewDataSource` from ViewController header

Comment: still same. Doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

could it possibly because in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you are referencing a generic table view?

try:

```
var cell = self.tblSettings.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SettingsCell") as! SettingsTableViewCell!
```

Comment: no luck yet :( I changed even the registration part too